# Writing an XML header with LXML

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm currently writing a script to convert a bunch of XML files from various encodings to a unified UTF-8.

I first try determining the encoding using LXML:

```
def get_source_encoding(self):
    tree = etree.parse(self.inputfile)
    encoding = tree.docinfo.encoding
    self.inputfile.seek(0)
    return (encoding or '').lower()
```

If that's blank, I try getting it from `chardet`:

```
def guess_source_encoding(self):
    chunk = self.inputfile.read(1024 * 10)
    self.inputfile.seek(0)
    return chardet.detect(chunk).lower()
```

I then use `codecs` to convert the encoding of the file:

```
def convert_encoding(self, source_encoding, input_filename, output_filename):
    chunk_size = 16 * 1024

    with codecs.open(input_filename, "rb", source_encoding) as source:
        with codecs.open(output_filename, "wb", "utf-8") as destination:
            while True:
                chunk = source.read(chunk_size)

                if not chunk:
                    break;

                destination.write(chunk)
```

Finally, I'm attempting to rewrite the XML header. If the XML header was originally

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255"?>
```

I'd like to transform it to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

My current code doesn't seem to work:

```
def edit_header(self, input_filename):
    output_filename = tempfile.mktemp(suffix=".xml")

    with open(input_filename, "rb") as source:
        parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding="UTF-8")
        tree = etree.parse(source, parser)

        with open(output_filename, "wb") as destination:
            tree.write(destination, encoding="UTF-8")
```

The file I'm currently testing has a header that doesn't specify the encoding. How can I make it output the header properly with the encoding specified?

Comment: Why do you need that encoding specification in the output?

Comment: I like to be... verbose about these things.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov if you don't specify the encoding of your output, how would the next person who needs to ingest that data know what encoding it is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
tree.write(destination, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

From [the API docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write):

> *xml_declaration* controls if an XML declaration should be added to the file. Use `False` for never, `True` for always, `None` for only if not US-ASCII or UTF-8 (default is `None`).

Sample from ipython:

```
In [15]:  etree.ElementTree(etree.XML('<hi/>')).write(sys.stdout, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hi/>
```

---

On reflection, I think you trying way too hard. `lxml` automatically detects the encoding and correctly parses the file according to that encoding.

So all you really have to do (at least in Python2.7) is:

```
def convert_encoding(self, source_encoding, input_filename, output_filename):
    tree = etree.parse(input_filename)
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as destination:
        tree.write(destination, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: How good at encoding guessing/transformation is it? I wanted to be sure that it'd transform things properly.

Comment: I have files with a header of `<?xml version="1.0"?>` without showing the encoding which is `windows-1255`, so I'm not sure how well it would work.

Comment: It seems to have worked well, but it [has caused other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813756/lxml-kills-my-cdata-sections).

Comment: As OP is using lxml, not the built-in etree lib, the linked docs website is incorrect. But as etree and lxml are quite alike, it works anyway. Here the correct [link](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation)