# LXML kills my CDATA sections

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

I'm batch-converting a lot of XML files, changing their character encodings to UTF-8:

```
with open(source_filename, "rb") as source:
    tree = etree.parse(source)

    with open(destination_filename, "wb") as destination:
        tree.write(destination, encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Unfortunately, it is destroying my `CDATA` sections and just escaping them instead.

**Source**:

```
<d><![CDATA[áÌÀøÅàùÑÄéú ëÌÄé áÈàÅùÑ éäå''ä ðÄùÑÀôÌÈè <small><small>(ùí ëå èæ)</small></small>
```

**Destination**:

```
<d>בְּרֵאשִׁית כִּי בָאֵשׁ יהו''ה נִשְׁפָּט &lt;small&gt;&lt;small&gt;(שם כו טז)&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/small&gt;
```

Is there a setting which I can set which will tell it to leave my CDATA sections alone? I'm mainly using LXML to change the character encoding and to write the XML header properly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`strip_cdata=False` option](http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata):

```
import lxml.etree as etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
with open(source_filename, "rb") as source:
    tree = etree.parse(source, parser=parser)
```