# Merge two XML files by matching elements by attribute value

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I have two XML files that I'm trying to merge. I looked at other previous questions, but I don't feel like I can solve my problem from reading those. What I think makes my situation unique is that I have to find elements by attribute value and then merge to the opposite file.

I have two files. One is an English translation catalog and the second is a Japanese translation catalog. Pleas see below.

In the code below you'll see the XML has three elements which I will be merging children on - MessageCatalogueEntry, MessageCatalogueFormEntry, and MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry. I have hundreds of files and each file has thousands of lines. There may be more elements than the three I just listed, but I know for sure that all the elements have a "key" attribute.

My plan:

- Iterate through File 1 and create a list of all the values of the "key" attribute.

  - In this example, the list would be `key_values = [321, 260, 320]`
- Next, I'll go through the key_value list one by one.
- I'll search File 1 for an element with attribute `key=321`.
- Next, grab the child of the element with `key=321` from File 1.
- Next, In File 2,find the element with `key=321` and add the child element I previously grabbed from File 1.
- Next I'll continue the same process looping through the `key_values` list.
- Next, I'll write the new xml root to a file being careful to keep the utf8 encoding.

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MessageCatalogue []>
<PackageEntry>
    <MessageCatalogue designNotes="Undefined" isPrivate="false" lastKey="362" name="AddKMRichSearchEngineAdmin_AutoTranslationCatalogue" nested="false" version="3.12.0">
      <MessageCatalogueEntry key="321">
        <MessageCatalogueEntry_loc locale="" message="active"/>
      </MessageCatalogueEntry>
      <MessageCatalogueFormEntry key="260">
        <MessageCatalogueFormEntry_loc locale="" shortTitle="Configuration" title="Spider Configuration"/>
      </MessageCatalogueFormEntry>
      <MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry key="320">
        <MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry_loc hintText="" label="Manage Recognised Phrases" locale="" mnemonic="" scriptText=""/>
      </MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry>
    </MessageCatalogue>
  </PackageEntry>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MessageCatalogue[]>
<PackageEntry>
  <MessageCatalogue designNotes="Undefined" isPrivate="false" lastKey="362" name="" nested="false" version="3.12.0">
    <MessageCatalogueEntry key="321">
      <MessageCatalogueEntry_loc locale="ja" message="アクティブ" />
    </MessageCatalogueEntry>
    <MessageCatalogueFormEntry key="260">
      <MessageCatalogueFormEntry_loc locale="ja" shortTitle="設定" title="Spider Configuration/スパイダー設定" />
    </MessageCatalogueFormEntry>
    <MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry key="320">
      <MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry_loc hintText="" label="認識されたフレーズを管理" locale="ja" mnemonic="" scriptText="" />
    </MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry>
  </MessageCatalogue>
</PackageEntry>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MessageCatalogue []>
<PackageEntry>
    <MessageCatalogue designNotes="Undefined" isPrivate="false" lastKey="362" name="AddKMRichSearchEngineAdmin_AutoTranslationCatalogue" nested="false" version="3.12.0">
      <MessageCatalogueEntry key="321">
        <MessageCatalogueEntry_loc locale="" message="active"/>
        <MessageCatalogueEntry_loc locale="ja" message="アクティブ" />
      </MessageCatalogueEntry>
      <MessageCatalogueFormEntry key="260">
        <MessageCatalogueFormEntry_loc locale="" shortTitle="Configuration" title="Spider Configuration"/>
        <MessageCatalogueFormEntry_loc locale="ja" shortTitle="設定" title="Spider Configuration/スパイダー設定" />
      </MessageCatalogueFormEntry>
      <MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry key="320">
        <MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry_loc hintText="" label="Manage Recognised Phrases" locale="" mnemonic="" scriptText=""/>
        <MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry_loc hintText="" label="認識されたフレーズを管理" locale="ja" mnemonic="" scriptText="" />
      </MessageCatalogueFormItemEntry>
    </MessageCatalogue>
  </PackageEntry>
```

I'm having trouble just even grabbing elements, nevermind grabbing them by key value. For example, I've been playing with the elementtree library and I wrote this code hoping to get just the MessageCatalogueEntry but I'm only getting their children:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree_japanese = et.parse('C:\\blah\\blah\\blah\\AddKMRichSearchEngineAdmin_AutoTranslationCatalogue_JA.xml')
root_japanese = tree_japanese.getroot()
MC_japanese =  root_japanese.findall("MessageCatalogue")

for x in MC_japanese:
    messageCatalogueEntry = x.findall("MessageCatalogueEntry")
    for m in messageCatalogueEntry:
        print et.tostring(m[0], encoding='utf8')

tree_english = et.parse('C:\\blah\\blah\\blah\\AddKMRichSearchEngineAdmin\\AddKMRichSearchEngineAdmin_AutoTranslationCatalogue.xml')
root_english = tree_english.getroot()
MC_english =  root_english.findall("MessageCatalogue")

for x in MC_english:
    messageCatalogueEntry = x.findall("MessageCatalogueEntry")
    for m in messageCatalogueEntry:
        print et.tostring(m[0], encoding='utf8')
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been at this for a few work days now and I'm not any closer to finishing than I was when I first started!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are getting the MessageCatalogEntry's. The problem is in the print statement. An element acts like a list, so `m[0]` is the first child of the MessageCatalogEntry. In

```
messageCatalogueEntry = x.findall("MessageCatalogueEntry")
for m in messageCatalogueEntry:
    print et.tostring(m[0], encoding='utf8')
```

change the print to `print et.tostring(m, encoding='utf8')` to see the right element.

I personally prefer lxml to elementtree. Assuming you want to associate entries by the 'key' attribute, you could use xpath to index one of the docs and then pull them into other doc.

```
import lxml.etree

tree_english = lxml.etree.parse('english.xml')
tree_japanese = lxml.etree.parse('japanese.xml')

# index the japanese catalog
j_index = {}
for catalog in tree_japanese.xpath('MessageCatalogue/*[@key]'):
    j_index[catalog.get('key')] = catalog

# find catalog entries in english and merge the japanese
for catalog in tree_english.xpath('MessageCatalogue/*[@key]'):
    j_catalog = j_index.get(catalog.get('key'))
    if j_catalog is not None:
        print 'found match'
        for child in j_catalog:
            print 'add one'
            catalog.append(child)

print lxml.etree.tostring(tree_english, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly as I needed. I really appreciate your help. I'd upvote you but I don't have enough reputation. I'll make sure to come back and do that when I qualify.
<br/>
One thing I'm curious about is that my headers (see below), if that's correct term, don't get written out. That's not a big deal though, I'll just write the strings to a file as the header is the same for all the files I'm working with.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE MessageCatalogue[]>  
Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, lxml expects you to output the header yourself. I don't remember all of the details.

Comment: I was wondering if you knew of another way to parse? The following code below removes CDATA tags which I need: tree_english = lxml.etree.parse('english.xml'). I checked the documenation and apparently you can keep the CDATA tags but it doesn't seem like they're using the same method to parse. Documentation here: http://lxml.de/2.1/api.html

Comment: Nevermind. I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813756/lxml-kills-my-cdata-sections