# Merge two XML files Python

Tags: python, xml, merge, elementtree

I have two XML files like below-
XML1

```
<root>
    <info>
        <order>2</order>
        <infoID>Information</infoID>
        <child>
            <info>
                <order>1</order>
                <infoID>AAAAA</infoID>
            </info>
            <info>
                <order>2</order>
                <infoID>BBBBB</infoID>
            </info>
            <info>
                <order>3</order>
                <infoID>CCC</infoID>
            </info>
            <info>
                <order>4</order>
                <infoID>DD</infoID>
            </info>
            <info>
                <order>5</order>
                <infoID>EEEEE</infoID>
            </info>
        </child>
    </info>
</root>
```

XML2

```
<root>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Data>
        <info>
            <desc>Data1</desc>
            <displayName>dID</displayName>
            <infoID>AAAAA</infoID>
            <type>String</type>
        </info>
        <info>
            <desc>Data2</desc>
            <displayName>sID/displayName>
            <infoID>BBBBB</infoID>
            <type>String</type>
        </info>
    </Data>
</root>
```

I'd like to combine them whenever the infoID matches like below, i.e., for example, when the infoID is AAAAA, it needs to get all the related lines under one child node.

```
<root>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Data>
        <info>
            <order>2</order>
            <infoID>Information</infoID>
            <child>
                <info>
                    <order>1</order>
                    <infoID>AAAAA</infoID>
                    <desc>Data1</desc>
                    <displayName>dID</displayName>
                    <type>String</type>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <order>2</order>
                    <infoID>BBBBB</infoID>
                    <desc>Data2</desc>
                    <displayName>sID/displayName>
                    <type>String</type>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <order>3</order>
                    <infoID>CCC</infoID>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <order>4</order>
                    <infoID>DD</infoID>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <order>5</order>
                    <infoID>EEEEE</infoID>
                </info>
            </child>
        </info>
</root>
```

I tried the below code but it just concatenates one file after another

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
out = open ("combined.xml", "wb")
class XMLCombiner(object):
    def __init__(self, filenames):
        assert len(filenames) > 0, 'No filenames!'
        self.roots = [et.parse(f).getroot() for f in filenames]

    def combine(self):
        for r in self.roots[1:]:
            self.combine_element(self.roots[0], r)
        return et.tostring(self.roots[0])

    def combine_element(self, one, other):
        one.attrib.update(other.attrib)
        mapping = {el.tag: el for el in one}
        for el in other:
            if len(el) == 0:
                try:
                    mapping[el.tag].text = el.text
                except KeyError:
                    mapping[el.tag] = el
                    one.append(el)
            else:
                try:
                    self.combine_element(mapping[el.tag], el)
                except KeyError:
                    mapping[el.tag] = el
                    one.append(el)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = XMLCombiner(('XML1.xml', 'XML2.xml')).combine()
    print >> out, r
```

Comment: `print >> out, r` is python?

Comment: @Elisha Yes. It might be used in some other language too, which I don't know, but it serves my purpose to write to a file for the time being. I might change it later to a more Pythonic way once I get the desired output.

Comment: @abn I'd suggest changing it *now*.

Comment: @Iplodman Would that make any difference, because it gives me the same output as the print statement, without writing to a file? I'm just curious. No offense.

Comment: @abn Of course not, but it's good practice. Better to start early ;P

Comment: Does the solution need to be fully generalized, or are all the XML1-type files similarly constrained to having only <order> tags that need to be brought across?

Comment: Hmm, this might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26770861/4099598

Comment: @NathanTuggy The "original" question you pointed at is not what I'm looking for. They have a set of key to be looked at unlike my case.

Comment: And, what, the <infoID> elements aren't keys? Same basic idea, just a different name and a slightly different structure.