# Can I use regex to merge two files in Python

Tags: python, regex, xml, merge, elementtree

I've posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258013/merge-two-xml-files-python) yesterday regarding merging two XML files. However, even after quite a few views, it didn't receive an answer. I now am wondering if I can use regex to merge the files whenever the content between "<>" matches and leave the unmatched content as it is? If so, I'd really appreciate any help.

Edit - I'd really appreciate if you could leave a constructive comment before down-voting.

Comment: Hi @NathanTuggy The other question is posted by me too. It doesn't have any answers in it. Hope you understand and remove the "possible duplicate" tag. When you mark a duplicate, it shows `This question may already have an answer here:
Merge two XML files Python`, where there's NO answer. Thanks!

Comment: Have you consider using xslt ?

Answer (score 0):

In a certain sense, you probably *could* use regexen for this. However, given how difficult it generally is to parse even XML (never mind other SGML dialects) with regexen, merging two such files is likely to prove even harder. I strongly recommend attempting a different solution.

Probably a bit of patience on your original question would work better.