# lxml/python reading xml with CDATA section

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, elementtree, cdata

In my xml I have a `CDATA` section. I want to keep the CDATA part, and then strip it. Can someone help with the following?

Default does not work:

```
$ from io import StringIO
$ from lxml import etree
$ xml = '<Subject> My Subject: 美海軍研究船勘查台海水文？ 船<![CDATA[&#xE9;]]>€ </Subject>'
$ tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
$ tree.getroot().text
' My Subject: 美海軍研究船勘查台海水文？ 船&#xE9;€ '
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813863/3321542) seems to suggest that a `parser` option `strip_cdata=False` may keep the cdata, but it has no effect:

```
$ parser=etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
$ tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml), parser=parser)
$ tree.getroot().text    
' My Subject: 美海軍研究船勘查台海水文？ 船&#xE9;€ '
```

Using `strip_cdata=True`,  which should be the default, yields the same:

```
$ parser=etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=True)
$ tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml), parser=parser)    
$ tree.getroot().text    
' My Subject: 美海軍研究船勘查台海水文？ 船&#xE9;€ '
```

Comment: If you add enough of the relevant XML, we might able to test.

Comment: Is that example not enough? I can add more.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's hard to read, with those numbers before your actual code and data. If they are not an important part of your question, remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDATA sections are not preserved in the `text` property of an element, even if `strip_cdata=False` is used when the XML content is parsed, as you have noticed. See https://lxml.de/api.html#cdata.

CDATA sections *are* preserved in these cases:

1. When serializing with `tostring()`:

   ```
   print(etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding="UTF-8").decode())
   ```
2. When writing to a file:

   ```
   tree.write("subject.xml", encoding="UTF-8")
   ```

Comment: Thanks for that. I read that part, but did not realise `etree.tostring` serialises.