# CDATA sections and comments are lost when parsing XML with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, cdata, xml-comments

I am editing xml files, I ran into the problem that when changing a file in a python script, its structure is lost.

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
  <element formatVersion="1.0">
    <firstValue>firstText</firstValue>
    <secondValue>secondText</secondValue>
    <thirdValue>thirdText</thirdValue>
    <errors>
      <path><![CDATA[path]]></path>
      <code_main />
    </errors>
    <reference>3</reference>
  </element>
  ....
</main>
```

Используя:

```
tree = ET.parse(xml_file).write("test.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

I lose all comments in the file, while if I compare the original file with the modified one using diff (in linux), the files are shown as completely different

Is there a way to change the xml file (my task is to add a subelement to `<element>`), while leaving the overall structure of the file unchanged, including comments and order.

The order and comments are fundamental in the file

UPD:

After executing the above code, I get it from the source xml in the following form:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<main>
  <element formatVersion="1.0">
    <firstValue>firstText</firstValue>
    <secondValue>secondText</secondValue>
    <thirdValue>thirdText</thirdValue>
    <errors>
      <path>path</path>
      <code_main />
    </errors>
    <reference>3</reference>
  </element>
</main>
```

Pay attention to `<path>`

Comments are also not saved at the same time:
Source:

```
<main>
  <element formatVersion="1.0">
    <firstValue>firstText</firstValue>
    <secondValue>secondText</secondValue>
    <thirdValue>thirdText</thirdValue>
    <errors>
      <path><![CDATA[path]]></path>
      <!--Stt-->
      <code_main />
    </errors>
    <reference>3</reference>
  </element>
</main>
```

Modified:

```
<main>
  <element formatVersion="1.0">
    <firstValue>firstText</firstValue>
    <secondValue>secondText</secondValue>
    <thirdValue>thirdText</thirdValue>
    <errors>
      <path>path</path>
      
      <code_main />
    </errors>
    <reference>3</reference>
  </element>
</main>
```

Comment: `<![CDATA[path]]>` is a CDATA section, not a comment.

Comment: Is it possible to save a section when changing a file?

Comment: It is possible to keep CDATA sections with lxml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813863/407651. lxml will also preserve comments.

Comment: unfortunately lxml also changes tags without saving the original data which I don't touch